# I have downloaded geotools . In which eclipse directory should I put it in for it to be fetched by my java file?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
package geotools.data.geojson;

import jts.geom.Coordinate;
import jts.geom.CoordinateSequence;
import jts.geom.Envelope;
import jts.geom.Geometry;
import jts.geom.GeometryCollection;
import jts.geom.LineString;
import jts.geom.MultiLineString;
import jts.geom.MultiPoint;
import jts.geom.MultiPolygon;
import jts.geom.Point;
import jts.geom.Polygon;
import jts.geom.impl.CoordinateArraySequence;
```

So where should jts and geotools go into for me to be able to access them ?

Answer (score 1):

There is an eclipse quickstart that answers your question; it provides instructions for both use of maven (which is more automatic); and for downloading the jars into a usable eclipse project.

- http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/eclipse.html

The eclipse download includes JTS (and other support libraries as needed).

Answer (score 0):

It should be added to the project's build-path if it's a JAR file.

Comment: In an eclipse ide , how do I do it ? Its a .zip file now

Comment: Give me the URL from where you downloaded, I'll have a look and tell you.